# Distance between fourier transforms

Tags: machine-learning, fourier-transform, functional-data-analysis

I am looking a fourier transform of probability function (a.k.a characteristic function).

for this topic [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/372876/296509) and the induced distance
$$ \|f-g\|_\mathcal{H}  = \int \frac{|\hat{(f-g)}(u)|^2}{\hat d(u)} \ du = \int \frac{|\int e^{ity}(f-g)(y)dy|^2}{\hat d(u)} \ du = \int \frac{|\hat f(u)-\hat g(u)|^2}{\hat d(u)} \ du$$

I tried to plot the distance between two normal distributions and choosing $d$ to be a fourier transform of Matern Kernel which has this form.

$$\hat d(u) = (1+\|u\|_2^2)^{-k/2}$$

$$\hat f(u) = e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}$$
$$\hat g(u) = e^{iu\mu-\frac{u^2}{2}}$$

with k to be some real number. The behavior of the distance is like below.
Hopefully, if the plot is correct, I have some problem to know why this has an oscillating behavior.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you are plotting: what do "mean" and "distance" correspond to in your formulas?  What does a Matern kernel have to do with finding a "distance between two normal distributions"?